# How to get the number of nodes in a GKE node pool as a stackdriver metric?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'm making a dashboard in GCP stackdriver.  We have a autoscaling node pool which the pods I'm interested in monitoring run in.  What I'm wondering is how do I monitor the amount of nodes the are currently running in the pool?

I've had a look at log based metrics, but I can't find anywhere in the logs where it actually says how many nodes are currently running.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no metric for number of nodes per se. We can get something similar though with the sum of `Total cores` grouped by `cluster_name`:

[image: stackdriver resource selection]

Comment: What if the node is a shared core vCPU like g1-small?

Comment: is there any way to get the number of nodes instead of the number of cores? Is there a way to do this with a Secondary Aggregator or something?

Answer (score 4):

Monitoring the `Instance Group/instance_group_size` metric will show the exact number of vms/nodes in your node pool. You can filter on the instance group's name associated to your node pool:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

in metric explorer use instance group as resource type and instance group size as metric.Then filter out instance group that is configured as node pool for GKE.

Comment: Please provide sources(link to documentation)

Answer (score 0):

In stack driver if you are using the new stack driver it will show the all the running node in an infrastructure part inside `kubernetes engine` menu.

If you will click on the node it will show all the containing `namespaces` of further you will click it will show all the running `pods` also.

for more deatils, you can check this out : https://medium.com/google-cloud/new-stackdriver-monitoring-for-kubernetes-part-1-a296fa164694